# Make a smart contract like SLA

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I have a problem. I need to write a smart contract using solidity. In this smart contract the service level provider will enter the details about the services which he will provide to customer, then he will send this contract information to customer address. If customer finds it right then he will confirm this contract and pay money to service provider on this address.

Can anyone tell me how to write this using solidity. I have only basic knowledge of writing smart contract in solidity.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is the Smart Contract and Distributed Application. Distributed Applications are use to interact with the Smart Contract with the User Interface.

In your scenario, you have two stakeholders the Service Provider and Customer. The Service Provider will enter the details of the services which can be store in the form of the String in the Smart Contract.

Whereas, when the Customer view the page through Distributed application, you will retrieve the information from the Smart Contract. And if the customer is interested you will initiate the payment method written in the Smart Contract.

The interaction between the Smart Contract and Distributed application is done with the help of Web3 library. Where as to design the front end you can use the AngularJs or truffle [framework](https://truffleframework.com/) as its well manage and has lots of [boxes](https://truffleframework.com/boxes) with ready made template for the Distributed Application.